# how to find tree comments by condition like where{articlId:id}

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

i have a tree comment and it have a mane to one relationship with article entity
the scema be like this

```
id  
body
userId
parentId
articleId
```

if i want to get the tree i use

```
this.commentsRepository.manager
      .getTreeRepository(Comments)
      .findTrees();
```

but the proplem is it gets all the comments with out to be able to select on condition
like where{articlId:id}